# Инициализация и вызов функции при работе с событиями JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции, события

очень часто надо повесить событие на resize/scroll window, например, мне надо чтобы при скролле у меня менялось fixed меню

```js
function fixedMenu() {
 $('.fixedMenu').addClass('fixed'); 
}
fixedMenu();
$(window).on('resize', fixedMenu);
```

для того чтобы все это дело нормально работало мне надо 1 раз вызвать функцию после ее инициализации, может как-то можно инициализировать функцию и сразу ее вызвать 1 раз, при этом иметь возможность вызвать ее еще раз внутри события scroll

Comment: а что именно не нравится в текущей реализации?

Comment: я не могу сказать что она мне не нравится, я учусь, и спрашиваю, может есть альтернативные решения, более удобные, например

Comment: удобство - весьма субъективно. я добавил несколько вариантов в ответе, но не совсем уверен, что это именно то, что хотелось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно возвращать себя же, получится так:

```
function fixedMenu() {
  $('.fixedMenu').addClass('fixed'); 
  return fixedMenu;
}

$(window).on('scroll', fixedMenu());
```

В этом случае функция выполнится перед навешиванием обработчика, вернет себя же, и установится в обработчик.

Но это не сильно отличается от способа приведенного в вопросе.

---

Но проще, просто сразу вызвать добавленный обработчик, например с помощью [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) или [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

```js
function fixedMenu() {
  console.log('scrolled');
  $('.fixedMenu').addClass('fixed');
}

$(window).on('scroll', fixedMenu).triggerHandler('scroll');
```

```css
.fixed {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixedMenu"></div>
```

Кроме того, навешивание одного обработчика для двух событий может выглядеть так

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', fixedMenu).triggerHandler('scroll');
```

Comment: вот это то что надо, спасибо)

Answer (score -3):

```
$(window).on('scroll', fixedMenu);
```

Comment: это запустит функцию только при скролле, а когда юзер загрузит страницу и ничего не будет скроллить, она не выполнится, т.к вызов на скролле

Comment: Можно вызвать функцию при загрузке страницы через событие "load"

Comment: `<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("All resources finished loading!");
  });
</script>`

Comment: @Alya вы не поняли вопроса